# What is the smallest OS with a VPN client and a web browser?

Tags: linux

What is the smallest OS you know of, with a GUI, VPN client and a web browser?
The best I have found so far is Puppy Linux, but can I go smaller?

Answer (score 2):

[DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) (Damn Small Linux) with the window manager of your choice ([E17](http://www.enlightenment.org/)?).

E17 (formerly known as Enlightenment) is a very slick and stylish and nonetheless lightweight window manager.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest operating system for the PC architecture i know of is MenuetOS (http://www.menuetos.net). It's written completly in x86 assembler and includes a TCP/IP stack, the assembler toolchain and a web browser. It fits on a single disc image. But it lacks the VPN feature, so you have to write it yourself in asm or try using something like hamachi as workaround.

Comment: well, hamachi would need to have support for the OS... so.. not likely it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Smallest OS I know is [KolibriOS](http://kolibrios.org/)

It's about 1.4 MB (floppy disk size) and features a GUI.

Comment: Does not feature a VPN client (yet) and only text-based web browser.